# How to use matrix from answer further?

Tags: matlab

If I write a random matrix (A) and get results:

ans = 1 2 3 4 %next row 5 6 7 8

how can I get it written in this form:

A = [1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8]; ?

(Of course I want to avoid retyping or copy-pasting it)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, `mat2str` is what you are looking for. Although it won't use commas, but spaces, and overwrite `ans`  (i.e. `ans` will be of type `char` afterwards).

Example (the second argument limits the number of digits):

```
>> rand(2,3); mat2str(ans,2)

ans =

[0.42 0.79 0.66;0.92 0.96 0.036]
```

Answer (score 1):

The last answer that you calculated is saved in a special variable named `ans`.  Simply assign that value to `A`.

```
% some calculations
[1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8]

% assign to A
A = ans;
```